# Adding html file to manifest.json file

Tags: json, google-chrome

I am new to google chrome extension development. I have started writing some codes for developing a chrome extension .I have created the manifest.json file and two other files named rotate.html,basic.html . i just need to add these two files to the manifest.json file .How can i do that .Here is my manifest.json file..

```
{


"name": "Hello World!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "My first Chrome extension.",
"manifest_version": "2",
  "browser_action": "{",
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
 }
```

}

Any help would be greately appreciated .Thanks ..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you looking for something like this?

```
 "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
```

Comment: i just need to add rotate.html and basic.html to json file

Comment: how do you use these files? when the user clicks on the extension icon the popup.html file will load in a popup in the above example. is that what you want?

Comment: no .i have created rotate.html which rotates the image which works fine when i checked it.Its about html and css and javascript ..The thing is that i want to add this file to json file so that i can rotate the image associated with the extension ..:)